# How do I set http referer?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to set up http referer before loading a website with cy.visit. How can I achieve this?

I got the following code:

```
cy.visit('https://www.whatsmyreferer.com/', {
  headers : {
    Referer : 'https://google.com/'
  }
})
```

I've tried to search through the documentation and search here but I couldn't find anything to solve this problem.

Comment: Which Cypress version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Adding headers to a `cy.visit()` request was added in 3.2.0.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#3-2-0) Update your installed Cypress version and try that again.

Here's a screenshot of the code from the OP running in Cypress 3.2.0:

[image: Screenshot of passing test from OP]

Comment: could you shart your test please. I am unable to change document.referrer in visit